# How to create direct download link for pdf

Tags: pdf, ftp, download

I have uploaded a pdf file in ftp server. The following link opens pdf file in the browser.

http://aptform.culinarysuperstars.com/Appointment_static.pdf

How to create a link for pdf file so that it is downloaded directly instead of opening in the browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locate the `.htaccess`-file on your FTP server. This is usually hidden, so you might have to make sure you can view and edit hidden files. You can then modify it to force downloads instead of showing up in the browser.

Include the following in the file:

```
AddType application/octet-stream .pdf
```

I am unsure whether this will work in any browser; if not, try the following in the `.htaccess`-file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
      ForceType application/octet-stream
      Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Method 2:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf)$" >
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working well in Chrome but not in Firefox. What should I do now? I updated the file with the 2nd suggestion.

Comment: Thanks again. Same issue. Working in chrome but not in fireFox.

Comment: I'm sorry but then I do not know what can make it work in Firefox. Maybe changing the link itself to the PDF would work.

Answer (score 0):

This is something you can't really control, it's based on browser/user settings.

If you're able to, you can try sending the header `Content-disposition: attachment; filename="Appointment_static.pdf"` with the file contents, which might trigger a download dialog rather than the file being shown in the browser, but you can't really rely on that.